Delphi Interface Inheritance Issue - Possible RT bug
I have an IGameEntityRef interface (an EntityRef is like the blueprint for the in-game entity, proving a common interface no matter what the Entity actually is). I then have an IResource interface, which inherits from IGameEntityRef, but adds a few properties which are unique to Resources in the game.
This is implemented in the game via TBaseEntityRef, which implements IGameEntityRef and TResourceRef which inherits from TBaseEntityRef and implements IResource.
I've added code and can replicate it, but also found out the issue, although I'm still not sure if it's supposed to raise an AV or not.
In the game I have an Array of IGameEntityRef, used to store all the EntityRef instances used in the game. When these are created, I use code like:
Function TEntityRefManager.CreateRef(<params>) : IGameEntityRef;
Begin
  Result := TResourceEntityRef.Create(self,IniType,sSectionName,INIValues);

End;

Creating them and assigning them to a varible of type IGameEntityRef means it never gets created & assigned to a variable of type IResource.
My presumption was that this was OK, because the object itself (TResourceEntityRef) implements IResource, so you should be able to cast it to an IResource, but you can't and doing so results in a general Access Violation, the text of which is meaningless as it's just an general 'you can't read from this address' error. You need to create it as an IResource FIRST and then you can store it as a IGameEntityRef and cast it to IResource later.
i.e. the code needs to be along the lines of:
Function TEntityRefManager.CreateRef(<params>) : IGameEntityRef;
var
   aResource : IResource;
   // Other interface types etc..
   aBuilding     : IBuilding; 
Begin
  aResource := TResourceEntityRef.Create(self,IniType,sSectionName,INIValues);
  Result := aResource;
End;

Create it this way and it won't create an access violation when you access a property of IResource.
I'll include the code so you can see it in action anyway, I still don't know if it's supposed to work or whether it is a bug in Delphi's RT.
unit example;

interface

Uses
  System.Classes, Generics.Collections;

type

  // Interfaces

  IGameEntityRef = interface
    ['{3EF2D8C1-C748-4742-91B2-BDA8F8EF56EC}']
    function GetName: string;
    Function GetININame : String;
    Property Name: string read GetName;
    Property ININame : String read GetININame;
  end;

  IResource = interface(IGameEntityRef)
    ['{D256C7CA-0C26-45B0-8543-BFCC8429D8E8}']
    Function  getResID : Integer;

    Property  ResourceId : Integer read getResID;
  end;

  // Classes

  TBaseEntityRef = Class (TInterfacedObject, IGameEntityRef)
    Private
    Protected
      fName : String;
      fININame : String;
      function GetName: string;
      function GetINIname : String;
    Public
      Constructor Create(EntityManager : IUnknown;iniFileType: Byte;sSectionName : String;INIValues : TStrings); virtual;

      Property Name: string read GetName;
      Property ININame: string read GetININame;

  End;

  TResourceEntityRef = Class (TBaseEntityRef, IResource)
    Private
      fResID : Integer;
      function getResID: Integer;
    Public
      Constructor Create(EntityManager : IUnknown;iniFileType: Byte;sSectionName : String;INIValues : TStrings); override;

      Property  ResourceId : Integer read getResID;
  End;

implementation

Var
  nResCnt : Integer;

{ TBaseEntityRef }

constructor TBaseEntityRef.Create(EntityManager: IInterface; iniFileType: Byte;
  sSectionName: String; INIValues: TStrings);
begin
  fININame := sSectionName;
  fName := INIValues.Values['name'];
end;

function TBaseEntityRef.GetINIname: String;
begin
  Result := fININame;
end;

function TBaseEntityRef.GetName: string;
begin
  Result := fName;
end;

{ TResourceEntityRef }

constructor TResourceEntityRef.Create(EntityManager: IInterface;
  iniFileType: Byte; sSectionName: String; INIValues: TStrings);
begin
  inherited;
  fResID := nResCnt;
  Inc(nResCnt);
end;

function TResourceEntityRef.getResID: Integer;
begin
  Result := fResID;
end;

initialization
  nResCnt := 0;

end.

And the program source:
program SOInterfaceQ;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  example in 'example.pas';

Var
  slTest : TStringList;
  aGenericEntity,aGenRef2 : IGameEntityRef;
  aResource : IResource;
begin
  try
    slTest := TStringList.Create;
    try
      slTest.Values['name'] := 'GenericEntity';
      aGenericEntity := TBaseEntityRef.Create(nil,1,'',slTest);

      slTest.Values['name'] := 'ResourceEntity';
      aResource := TResourceEntityRef.Create(nil,1,'',slTest);

      WriteLn('IGameEntityRef Name: ' + aGenericEntity.Name);
      WriteLn('IResource Name: ' + aResource.Name);
      WriteLn('IResource ResId: ' + IntToStr(aResource.ResourceId));

      // Ok, this all works, what about if we assign an IResource to IGameEntityRef

      // In the game we store an array of EntityRefs of the base
      // interface, i.e. 'var aERList : TArray<IGameEntityRef>;' Other EntityTypes inherit from the base interface
      // and add their own properties to it, i.e. IResource

      aGenericEntity := Nil; // I know you don't need to, but for readibility's sake...
      aGenericEntity := aResource;

      // Test casting an IGameEntityRef to a IResource - this works
      WriteLn('aGenRef2 ResId: ' + IntToStr(IResource(aGenRef2).ResourceId));

      // But if you create the same TResourceEntityRef and assign to a IGameEntityRef
      // it will AV when you try and access ResourceId (which is defined in IResource)

      aGenericEntity := Nil;
      aGenericEntity := TResourceEntityRef.Create(nil,2,'',slTest);

      // This will error
      WriteLn('aGenericEntity cast as IResource ResId: ' + IntToStr(IResource(aGenericEntity).ResourceId));
    finally
      slTest.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.

Delphi version: 12(.1?) (Embarcadero® Delphi 12 Version 29.0.51961.7529)

Which version of Delphi are you using? What is the complete error message of the AV?  What does the implementation of getResID look like? Please provide a [mcve] that actually compiles.

Why do developers (with nearly 2000 reputation) leave out critical parts of code when asking what is wrong with it?

I've seen this with many highscore accounts: after many years they seem to fall back into behaving like beginners for this website (or for reasonable communication logic). Maybe they're too fed up with much and only aim for quick shots? The unindented code indicates this, too.

Because I was asking if there was a known issue or whether I had got the wrong idea about Interfaces. As for unindented code, OK, I'll edit the code if it was unreadable to you ;)

@AmigoJack, tbh it was a quick question, I was asking whether Interfaces should be able to work this way or whether I had misunderstood them. Tbh, I was expecting a comment along the lines of 'That looks OK, but some demo code would help / no, they don't work like that'. I'll update with some code.
